# How to remove SSRF vulnerability(CWE ID 918) from http.NewRequestWithContext() function in golang?

Tags: go, veracode, go-http, url-validation, ssrf

We are facing the issue of SSRF vulnerability in `http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", url, nil)` function in Golang during Veracode scan.

The URL that is coming to this function contains jwt token as an additional parameter in the last.
eg, https://this.isAValidUrl.com/path?token=--validJwtToken--

We tried to fix the problem in 2 ways by validating the URL using:

1. regex which validates any valid http/https URL.
2. allowed list of specified URLs only.

Both fixes are not working and still we are getting some issues in the Veracode scan.
Can someone please help with this?

Comment: To me, it looks like either you or Veracode misinterprets the problem. As you can see in [the description of CWE-918](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/918.html), SSRF is about blindly using an URL received as a parameter in an incoming HTTP request–so basically an attacker may be able to submit your server program arbitrary URL that program will perform a request to (and that's why it's "server-side"). A JWT token is not a URL, so hence my guess is that either you're misinterpreting the problem Veracode reports or Veracode has false positive.

Comment: In either case, this question is not for [go] tag on StackOverflow. It may be fit for https://security.stackexchange.com/ but anyway it would require way more details in order to be answerable. You might also try other venues of communication about programming in Go which allow multiple backs-and-forths (which SO does not)–see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community). Mailing list or forum should be okay.

Comment: @kostix the url passed to the function is a valid https url which we are reading from env files. JWT token is just the last parameter appended in this URL. We have tried validation in 2 ways but not sure exactly how should we fix this problem. Thanks for your feedback, we will also try to ask on other platforms as well. :)